Why sand dunes appear dark in Sentinel-1 SAR Images but bright in optical images
I am working on flood mapping and boundary analysis using Sentinel-1 SAR data in Google Earth Engine, and I've noticed that certain features, which I suspect are sand dunes, appear very dark in the radar imagery. However, when I compare these areas in optical images (Sentinel-2), they appear bright, supporting the idea that they are sand dunes.


Additionally, I’m observing these features in both VV and VH polarizations. Are there any known methods to better distinguish sand dunes in SAR data, or insights on handling such low-backscatter areas effectively for flood mapping?
Below is the code snippet.
var roi = ee.Geometry.Point([69.590958, 26.427164]);
var dateRange = {from: '2022-08-15', to: '2022-09-15'};

var s1img = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
                  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
                  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
                  .filterBounds(roi)
                  .filterDate(dateRange.from, dateRange.to);

var s1imgVV = s1img.select('VV');
var s1imgVH = s1img.select('VH');
print(s1imgVV.size());
s1imgVV = s1imgVV.mean();
s1imgVH = s1imgVH.mean();

var s2img = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED')
                  .filterBounds(roi)
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
                  .filterDate(dateRange.from, dateRange.to);

var s2imgbands = s2img.select('B4', 'B3', 'B2');
print(s2imgbands.size());
s2imgbands = s2imgbands.mean();

Map.centerObject(roi, 9);
Map.addLayer(s2imgbands, {min: 240, max: 2300}, 'Sentinel-2');
Map.addLayer(s1imgVV, {min: -24, max: -1.5}, 'Sentinel-1 VV');
Map.addLayer(s1imgVH, {min: -31, max: -10}, 'Sentinel-1 VH');


The most common component of sand, silica is silicon dioxide (SiO2) and is usually in the form of quartz. Quartz is a hard, and highly reflecting.

The dark color in the radar image can have two reasons, either the dunes have a smoother surface than their surroundings or they are dryer. Radar is sensitive to both roughness and conductivity / moisture (the higher the stronger the backscatter).

I would say they are smoother, because they are bare while the surrounding area have vegetation (visible in Google satellite)
